# minikube start on Centos7

Tags: docker, centos, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to start minikube on centos 7, using VirtualBox 5.1, but it gives me this error:

```
E0823 19:26:32.888702   40645 start.go:129] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory.
```

If you have any recommendations, how to fix it, please, give me a couple of advices. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quiet easy.

Because when you typing minikube start, it will automatically create a virtual Linux guest, running in virtualbox or kvm or sth.
So, reboot and booting into you BIOS settings, turn on virtualization features(VT-X/AMD-v). And make sure you have virtualbox(minikube default) installed (or kvm ), and make sure you can ping gcr.io.

minikube start -h to see 
--vm-driver string                VM driver is one of: [virtualbox kvm none] (default "virtualbox")

Comment: So, I forgot to add, that I have Centos7 on my Virtual Machine. I do not completely understand, what I have to do. Sould I reboot Centos7 and boot it into BIOS settings?

Comment: You can’t do the nested virtualization. run minikube on the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

when running minikube on the host machine，you can add  "--vm-driver=none",that means no virtual Machine